# UWP App not accessed by every user

Tags: uwp, installation

I created Uwp app in visual studio and created app packages for test purposes.

I have two users in my domain now I installed my app on my windows tablet using one user. I use powershell add-appxpackage command It gets installed and is working well but when I login from a different user on my tablet it is not able to find the UWP app.

I wanted multiple users to read and write file in a shared location for all my users so my app creates it in a shared location and my other user is able to see the created file and access it but it is not able to find the app.

I tried with Add-AppxProvisionedPackage and it displays the result fine but when i search for app it is not there.

Do I need to give it some permission or is my installation wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to install an app package for all users using the `Add-ProvisionedAppxPackage` cmdlet. See the documentation [here for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/add-appxprovisionedpackage?view=win10-ps).

Comment: Yeah I tried this it shows the result fine but app does not get installed