# Allow UWP-app to be installed in System Context

Tags: ionic-framework, uwp, appx, intune

I developed an UWP-app and packaged it as appx-file. The app works fine and can be installed in Win10.

Now I want to deploy this app via Intune to the system context. Unfortunately, the app can only be installed in user context. I already tried to package the app as msi-file (via WIX Toolset). But this leads to the same problem.

Does anyone know, how I can adjust my UWP-app to be able to install the app in the system context instead of the user context?

I really appreciate your response!

Answer (score 2):

The responses of a similars question :

Install Windows Store App package (*.appx) for all users:
https://superuser.com/questions/647927/install-windows-store-app-package-appx-for-all-users

UWP App not accessed by every user:
[UWP App not accessed by every user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49124478/uwp-app-not-accessed-by-every-user)