# How to run UWP application in selected Windows desktop

Tags: c#, c++, windows, api

I have desktop created by Windows API CreateDesktop function. On this desktop I run the application through the CreateProcess or CreateProcessAsUser functions. In the STARTUPINFO structure passed as a parameter to CreateProcess I set lpDesktop to my desktop name.

Everything works fine if I run a "standard" Windows application. But UWP applications always run on the default Windows desktop!  I also tried to run UWP applications by LaunchWinApp.exe with the parameter - but without success. UWP applications always run on the default desktop. 
So how to run UWP application on selected desktop?

Comment: Probably has something to do with UWP apps not being regular apps and are installed by default for the `current user`.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49124478/uwp-app-not-accessed-by-every-user) to get around it

Comment: @MickyD I think it probably has nothing to do with my problem. In my case the application is installed and launched as the currently logged in user. The only difference is that the user works on a non-default desktop. However, despite all my attempts, the UWP application always starts on the default desktop.

Comment: UWP apps aren’t installed in typical locations such as Program Files but in an isolated file system.  Just _how_ are you running it anyway?  You might find that you can’t remote run a UWP app in a child Windows Station

Comment: @MickyD I tried to run UWP applications in various ways: via CreateProcess, ShellExecuteEx, LaunchWinApp.exe etc. I have no problem running the application - they launch but always on default desktop. So they are invisible to the user because he can only see windows belonging to the current desktop